# Problem when opening a script file in IDA (syntax error)(pe_sections.idc)

Tags: ida, script, error

I downloaded the script files from http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/57/PE_Scripts.

Then i extracted the files in the folder idc in the IDA folder (C:\Program Files\IDA 7.0\idc)

I opened IDA (64 bits) normally and load the PE program , and when i do File>script files> and then select pe_sections.idc the program give me this error :

```
C:\Program Files\IDA 7.0\idc\pe_sections.idc: C:\Program Files\IDA 7.0\idc\pe_sections.idc,1887: Syntax error near: 0x8
```

Is there anything i can do ? i am trying to do patch and changing on the program , thanks for any help .

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the 2003 version of pe_sections.idc.  There were some bugs in the older versions related to parsing x64 files.  We were learning both IDC scripting and the details of the x64 format at the same time.

Comment: can you please give me the link toa newer version ?